# how to set different id in distributed system for different computer

Tags: twitter, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

how to set different id in distributed system for different computer?
Twitter's snowflake arithmetic can generate id in distributed system. Every different computer has a 'workerId'. 
so How to set a different workerId when I start tomcat and tell applation.

Answer (score 0):

Arthur, for the context of this question, are you talking about this: https://www.callicoder.com/distributed-unique-id-sequence-number-generator/
In this article they talk about Twitter snowflake, not Snowflake, the Cloud Data Warehouse.

What you can do with Snowflake if you are considering moving your sharded database for your application to a high performing data base check out that solution that was linked above.

Hope that helps!